# Interesting list behaviour in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

In python 2.7:

```
>>> a=[0,1,2,3]
>>> b=a
>>> for i in range(0,4):
...     if i==2:
...         b.remove(a[i])
>>> a
[0, 1, 3]
>>> b
[0, 1, 3]
>>>
```

Why?

I need the difference between **a** and **b** and i am removing from list **b**

---

Ok. I am extending the question.

I am cloning the objects which are containing this lists.

Ex:

```
class Ogr():
   a=[]
   .
   .
   .
   fillA():
      ...
      self.a=[0,1,2,3]

_______________________________________

ogr_temp=copy.copy(ogr)
for i in range(0,4):
   if i==2:
      ogr_temp.remove(ogr[i])
ogr
>>>    [0, 1, 3]
ogr_temp
>>>    [0, 1, 3]
```

---

Everytime must i clone all the lists in the class?

Comment: `b` and `a` are the same list, with different name. I think this question has been answered a zillion times on stackoverflow.

Comment: i think it's up to two zillion by now

Comment: so how can i clone ? Because in real code i am cloning the object which contains these lists, not lists

Comment: Your `Ogr` is a bit confused about class variables and instance variables. I fear the `a=[]` doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: I know but i try to make it more simple. But whole of code is more complex than this.(approx. 200 line of code for class and assign of the lists). But your answer is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use `deepcopy`.

```
from copy import copy, deepcopy

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = [1,2,3,4]

mc = MyClass()
mc2 = mc
mc3 = copy(mc)
mc4 = deepcopy(mc)
```

Demo:

```
>>> id(mc)
139688808587984
>>> id(mc.a)
33373792
>>> id(mc2)
139688808587984
>>> id(mc2.a)
33373792
>>> id(mc3)
139688808537360
>>> id(mc3.a)
33373792
>>> id(mc4)      #mc4 is a different object than mc
139688808537808
>>> id(mc4.a)    #and mc4.a is a different object than mc.a
33404544         #any changes you make to mc4.a will not affect mc.a
```

Answer (score 3):

`a` and `b` are the same list.

If you want a clone, use `b = a [:]`. (Basically create a slice from beginning to end.)

If you have an object that has list members (as you pointed out in your comment), try this:

```
class A:
    def __init__ (self, lst = None): #Beware of mutable default arguments
        self.myList = lst [:] if lst else []

    def clone (self):
        return A (self.myList)
```

---

Example:

```
>>> a = A([1,2,3])
>>> b = a.clone()
>>> a.myList.append('only in a')
>>> print (a.myList)
[1, 2, 3, 'only in a']
>>> print (b.myList)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in real code i am cloning the objects which are containing these lists. So what may i to do?

Comment: Thanks for your answer instead of -1 vote like others do. This may be the solution. Thanks for your understanding and effort (:

Comment: Glad to help. I think the downvotes were motivated because you reduced your original problem to something too general (and basically created a X-Y-Problem thus).

Comment: Approx. 200 line of code for this and all objects in the code are instances of other objects. What may i do? The original code is more unreadable if u don't know the structure of application (:

Anyway i see 2 kind of people in here.Some for help, and some for downvote for satisfy their big ego's (:

Comment: All objects anywhere are instances of other objects (or of themselves in the unique case of `<class type>`)...